# Meteor-Ionic - hide safari address bar and tab bar

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework

I've used the wonderful Meteor-Ionic combo for app, but when I view it on my iPhone I can still see the Safari address bar at the top and the Safari tab-bar at the bottom of the screen.

Apologies if this a newbie question, but I've been looking for a solution for hours, without any luck.

is if possible to hide either and hopefully both bars?

Comment: Did you use [Meteoric](http://meteoric.github.io/) ? If yes, it should not be the case. Can you share your code with problem. Feel free too ask Meteoric developer on this [twitter handle](https://twitter.com/nwientge), he may also be able to help. Please share the code, that will help to answer better.

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities to modify Safari's UI from a mobile website are quite limited.

You could use the following META tag which hide the bars:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="......,minimal-ui">
```

But it has been removed in iOS 8 version and it was only available from iOS 7.1.

Another tag could be used:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

But this is only working when the user adds your website as an application on his homescreen.

I think the best solution is to wrap your application in a Cordova webview using Meteor build tools, see there: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration.
Thus, you won't have any UI apart the one you provide in you webapp.